# google sheets regex multiply values in cell by integer in in same cell

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, flatten

I struggled to find something to answer this, perhaps I'm simply looking for the wrong question:

I have a field that people may put a string into, such as:

```
colA

G7
2xC55 1xG7
G7
C55
```

I'm attempting to compare the number of instances by a value (listing the unique values in one column!). Ultimately I want it to read:

```
colB   colC

G7     3
C55    3
```

however, using `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A4,A1:A2))` Column B will write:

```
col B

G7
2xC55 1xG7
C55
```

And if I try to count the number of instances of a value using `=COUNTIF(A1:A4,"*"&B1&"*")` it will read, in whole:

```
col A        col B       col C

G7           G7          3
2xC55 1xG7   2xC55 1xG7  1
G7           C55         2
C55
```

So again, how would I make columns B and C read:

```
colB   colC

G7     3
C55    3
```

I have other issues, but once I figure this out, I should be able to apply it forward (as it seems to be a confusing regex extraction + listing all in one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFNA(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(REPT(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A4, " "), 
 "(?:\d+x)?(.+)")&"×", IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A4, " "), "(\d+)x"), 1)*1)), "×"))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect for my question. As an extension, if I needed it to ignore blank cells in between, what modifications should be made? Currently, it returns `#VALUE!` in the first cell, with the number of blank cells as the second column.

Comment: @MackenzieFritschle change IFNA to IFERROR and see if that helps